# Linq Group By with Count and Key Name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm attempting to get the company name from a table in which I create the new anonymous type after a group.  The query works if I comment out the "CompanyName" Line

```
db.tbl
.GroupBy(a => a.ID)
.Select(b => new {
    // This line is where I need help, I want to grab the company name
    CompanyName = b.GroupBy(x=>x.CustomerName).ToString(),
    CustomerId = (int) b.Key,
    TotalQuotes = b.Count()
})
```

Comment: Which is the question, sir?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, how do I get CompanyName?

Comment: First off, where is "c"?

Comment: `db.tbl
.GroupBy(a => a.ID)
.Select(b => new {
    // This line is where I need help, I want to grab the company name
    CompanyName = b.First().CustomerName,
    CustomerId = (int) b.Key,
    TotalQuotes = b.Count()
})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to Group each list again.

As I suppose the CustomerName will be the same for all the entities part of a Group, you can simply take the first entity and extract from it the `CustomerName`:

```
db.tbl
    .GroupBy(a => a.ID)
    .Select(c => new {
        CompanyName = c.First().CustomerName,
        CustomerId = (int) c.Key,
        TotalQuotes = c.Count()
    });
```

Comment: This worked, I'm used to the SQL syntax in which I have to use the GroupBy or Function to select a field.